# Entity Framework core, foreign key constraint due to cascade delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core with a code-first approach and ASP.NET MVC.

Building a mini-clone of a game I've played as practice. A player has villages, a village has resource fields, and armies that can move between villages. They can attack, and whatnot. Just started working on the army aspect of it and I'm getting the following error when running `dotnet ef database update` (migrations add works fine):

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Army_Villages_VillageId' on table 'Army' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

A somewhat clear message I suppose, and I've found 4-5 topics covering this. But I cannot get any solutions to work. In a situation like this, if I try to delete an object that is related to another object through a foreign key, it will cause a cascade of deletions, where the related objects are also deleted. Which I'm guessing is the problem here.

A screenshot of the database if anyone is interested:

[image: Drawing of the database]

I've tried specifying `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);` in `OnModelCreating`. It looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Army>()
            .HasOne(t => t.Village)
            .WithMany(a => a.Armies)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.VillageId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

But that does absolutely nothing.

You used to be able to add the following to `OnModelCreating`:

```
builder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

That does not work in EF Core, but supposedly this is the new way to do it:

```
foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
{
    relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
}
```

But this results in the same error for me.

Some threads suggest the problem has to do with properties not being nullable. Thus I tried setting the props inside `Army` to this:

```
public int? VillageId { get; set; }
public Village? Village { get; set; }
```

The army class looks like this:

```
public Army()
{
}

public int ArmyId { get; set; }
public Tile Location { get; set; }
public ArmyStatus ArmyStatus { get; set; }

public List<Troop> Troops { get; set; } = new List<Troop>();

// Navigation props
public int? VillageId { get; set; }
public Village? Village { get; set; }
```

and `Village` like this:

```
public Village()
{
}

[Key]
public int VillageId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

// Navigation props
public virtual ICollection<ResourceField> ResourceFields { get; set; }
public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
public int PlayerId { get; set; }

public virtual VillageData VillageData { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Army> Armies { get; set; }

public int TileId { get; set; }
public virtual Tile Tile { get; set; }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

When I also declared `Armies` in the `Village` class nullable, it worked.

```
public virtual ICollection<Army>? Armies { get; set; }
```

Though it has happened before with EF core that I need to delete migrations, the DB, and save every file 3 times over, then repeat the same thing twice, and it suddenly works. So I'm not sure it was actually making it nullable that made it work.

In OnModelCreating I only kept:

```
foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }
```